# Defining a:focus selector

Tags: less

I have the below HTML structure.

```
<html>
    <a class="customcssstyle" href="#'>Link</a>
</html>
```

Now I need to have a style, such that on `focus` on the link , it should appear in red.

For that in normal CSS, we write it as:

```
a.customcssstyle:focus
{
    color:red;
}
```

May I know how we can write it using Less CSS.

Comment: You can write it the same way as CSS. Less accepts CSS syntax.

Comment: like this ? `customcssstyle { a { &:focus {}}}` ?

Comment: @balaji: Happy to help. Do make note of the edits I made to the question, typically those edits would happen to all posts because they are considered as fluff and not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS syntax is valid in less. But also you can do something like:

```
.customcssstyle
{
    a {
        &:focus {
           color:red;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: a is an inline element and should be inside a block element (not html). Then in css for calling a class you need a dot, e.g. .customcssstyle and not the value of the attribute class only. At least to select the focus state of this element just call the class with the pseudo selector :focus.

```
.customcssstyle:focus {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the mention Alexander , I edited it as you suggested